# Scan for components in services module of multi module maven spring project

Tags: spring, maven

I have a Maven Multi Module project with the following struture:

- Site-Parent
  -- Site-UI
  -- Site-Entities
  -- Site-Services
  -- Sites-Repository

My Site-UI web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysite.app.web.spring</param-value>
`</context-param>
```

AppConfig.java within com.mysite.app.web.spring:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:contextConfig.xml",
        "classpath*:securityConfig.xml" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mysite.app.web.controller")
public class AppConfig
{
    @Bean
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter()
    {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

WebConfig.java within com.mysite.app.web.spring:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.mysite.app.web.controller" })
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    public WebConfig()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry reg)
    {
        reg.addInterceptor(new BaseInterceptor());
        reg.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor());
        //reg.addInterceptor(new AddCardInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Here is one of my controllers:

```
@Controller
public class PurchaseController extends AppController
{
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PurchaseController.class);

    @Autowired
    private IPurchaseService purchaseService;

        ...
}
```

I get the following error when starting up the app:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'purchaseController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mysite.services.IPurchaseService com.mysite.app.web.controller.PurchaseController.purchaseService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mysite.services.IPurchaseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mysite.services.IPurchaseService com.mysite.app.web.controller.PurchaseController.purchaseService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mysite.services.IPurchaseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mysite.services.IPurchaseService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 25 more
```

I know it is because my services are not been scanned.

I have the following in my services module:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mysite.services")
public class ServicesConfig
{
}
```

What I need to know is how can I configure my app to scan them? 
I want to maintain as much configuration in code as possible and avoid using xml files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution.

I need to specify the package location of my spring config files for each module, I do this in the web.xml in my Site-UI module.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mysite.app.web.spring com.mysite.services.spring com.mysite.persistence.spring</param-value>
</context-param>
```

There may be a better way of doing this and I'm open to suggestions.